# Lines of a StreamReader to an array of string

Tags: string, c#-4.0, streamreader

I want to get a `string[]` assigned with a `StreamReader`. Like:

```
try{
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("a.txt");
    do{
        str[i] = sr.ReadLine();
        i++;
    }while(i < 78);
}
catch (Exception ex){
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
```

I can do it but can't use the string[]. I want to do this:

```
MessageBox.Show(str[4]);
```

If you need further information feel free to ask, I will update.
thanks in advance...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you really want a string array, I would approach this slightly differently. Assuming you have no idea how many lines are going to be in your file (I'm ignoring your hard-coded value of 78 lines), you can't create a `string[]` of the correct size up front.

Instead, you could start with a collection of strings:

```
var list = new List<string>();
```

Change your loop to:

```
using (var sr = new StreamReader("a.txt"))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        list.Add(line);
    }
}
```

And then ask for a string array from your list:

```
string[] result = list.ToArray();
```

#### Update

Inspired by [Cuong's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12634805/74757), you can definitely shorten this up. I had forgotten about this gem on the `File` class:

```
string[] result = File.ReadAllLines("a.txt");
```

What `File.ReadAllLines` does under the hood is actually identical to the code I provided above, except Microsoft uses an `ArrayList` instead of a `List<string>`, and at the end they return a `string[]` array via `return (string[]) list.ToArray(typeof(string));`.

Comment: @whoone: See my updated answer. There's a nice shortcut that will save you a few lines of code.

Comment: I don't find System.IO.File in the add reference. Do you have the solution?

Comment: `File` is part of the CLR. You just need to import `System.IO`.

Comment: ReadAllLines throws an error stating that the file is in use for me.  I had to go back to using a streamreader  with File.Open for my solution.  Anyone have any idea how to use "FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite" paramters that you have in File.Open with File.ReadAllLines?

Comment: `File.ReadAllLines` opens a `FileStream` with the parameters `FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read`. Using a `StreamReader` as you have described would be one valid solution.